# Inputenc/Pandoc error when knit to Pdf on Rstudio Version 0.98.994

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am getting an error to knit a Rmd document to pdf. Here is the part of the code causing the error.

````
```{r chunk5 ,echo=F}

hypoconf<-function(z){if(z=="dose"){

                 cat(paste(as.character(1),"\b. If there is no difference in 
                 tooth  growth  for" ,z,   "of",as.character(20),"and"     
                 as.character(10),"the probability of seeing the     
                 observed or more extreme outcome is", as.character(30),"percent."))  

                 cat("\n\n") 
            }
hypoconf("dose")  
```
````

This throws the following error when knitting to pdf.

```
output file: report2.knit.md

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source.
! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `utf8'.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.260 \end{verbatim}

Try running pandoc with --latex-engine=xelatex.
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Execution halted
```

I do not get the same error when I knit to html instead. Also, I have figured out the sources of error are the backspace `\b` and the newline `\n` characters in my code. But I cannot find a way to get around this.

Comment: Have you tried what the error recommands? "Try running pandoc with --latex-engine=xelatex." (this can be done with `latex-engine:xelatex` added under pdf_output in the YAML header

Comment: @scoa In this case, using the `tidy =F` option in the r-code chunk seems to have worked for me. Thanks anyway. Am i supposed to delete the question now?

Comment: actually, you should post this as an answer and accept it, it might be useful to someone else who has a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `tidy =F` option in the r-code chunk seems to have removed the error for me.